# Reducing AWS RDS Database Size

Tags: django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently, I am running an r3.large database on RDS. It is costing me a lot of money, and I do not need a database that large at this time.

Is there a way to reduce this database, without losing all of its content?

For example, is there a way to copy its content, launch a smaller database, and then load the content onto the new database?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the instance type to a cheaper one and increase it as needed.

Take a look to http://www.n2ws.com/how-to-guides/how-to-modify-rds-instance-types.html

Answer (score 1):

If your using MySQL then its easy.

**Step 1 :** Just go to -> **`Instance actions`**.
[image]

**Step 2 :** Select modify option from there change the **`DB Instance Class`** type to any flavour you want, also you can change the size of RDS instance if you want to lessen the storage space also.

[image]

**Note**: You can increase or decrease space and instance class anytime you want. I recommend to read more about it on AWS site.